# How to get the total height of ACE Editor documents?

Tags: javascript, css, ace-editor

I searched the internet and found this:

```
editor.getSession().getDocument().getLength() * editor.renderer.lineHeight + editor.renderer.scrollBar.getWidth()
```

But it is assuming there's no line wraps. If I have set `editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);` It will don't work, giving the wrong height.

How can I get the total height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `session.getScreenLength() * editor.renderer.lineHeight` or `editor.renderer.layerConfig.maxHeight`
See https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.5/lib/ace/virtual_renderer.js#L966

Comment: Though this seems to be working, I cannot find anything in the docs about `layerConfig`. Any idea why?

Comment: sadly the documentation is not very thorough

Answer (score 0):

I have a tricky solution which works now.

```
editor.getSession().documentToScreenPosition(editor.getSession().getDocument().getLength(), 0).row * editor.renderer.lineHeight + editor.renderer.scrollBar.getWidth()
```

Very wasty.